# Try and Catch error / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, try-catch

I have the following PHP code:

```
try{ 
    $article_ID =$_GET["articleID"];  
    if(!$article_ID) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid query: ". mysql_error());
    }
    else {
        $select_query = mysql_query("SELECT articleContent, articleTitle From articles WHERE articleID=$article_ID AND typeID=$type_ID");
    }
}
catch(Exception $e) { 
    //echo $e->getMessage();
    $select_query = mysql_query("SELECT articleContent, articleTitle From articles       WHERE typeID=$type_ID");
}
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_query); 
echo '<h1>'.$row['articleTitle'].'</h1>';
echo  $row['articleContent'];
```

The condition in the if statment (`if(!$article_ID)` ) should try to get the value in get method, and if it can't so it will throw exception and pass to the `catch` part, it works fine, but I see error message in my webpage any time it comes to the catch (`Notice: Undefined index: articleID on line 6`) why? and how can I hide this message?

Comment: this question many time asked, use `isset($_GET["articleID"])`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notices do not throw exceptions. The notice is in the first line, because there is no "ArticleID" key in $_GET array variable.

I think you could do something like this

```
$articleID = isset($_GET["articleID"]) ? $_GET["articleID"] : '';
```